# Video site requests Adblocker to be shut off, next day I have 3 "weird" bookmarks

Tags: linux, malware, web-browser, attacks, javascript

I was on a site trying to view a video and the site requested that I turn off my adblocker to view the video.

So I did and then the next day I noticed that I had 3 "weird" bookmarks in my bookmark bar. They were just keyword bookmarks like: "play poker", "buy stuff", "pics", that type of thing, and upon mouse over, I noticed they all had link shorteners. I didn't click any of them, so I don't know where they led.

Funny enough, this was the only questionable site that I had visited on my laptop right after a fresh install of Linux, so I'm pretty certain that this specific site was the culprit.

What are these things and what can be done in a situation like this?
Browser is Chromium v43.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is a wrong, spam practice but it does not cause other inconvenience over the spam aspect.

Browsers allow JavaScript code initiated by a user click to add bookmarks in order to allow websites to propose friendly "Bookmark this site" buttons. However such functionality can be exploited in order to store unwanted bookmarks in visitors browser linking to remunerated links (pay per click abuse).

Comment: This is incorrect. Bookmarks cannot be added programmatically via JavaScript in Chrome (which is what the OP is using). Extensions can do it if they have the right permissions set, but not regular webpages.